# How To Determine Frequency Of Overlapping Polygons (Bounding-Boxes)

Tags: geoprocessing, analysis

My starting point is a series of bounding box polygons, representing the extents of all the data sets in my inventory.

I am trying to produce an output grid showing the frequency of coverage over the the extent of the entire inventory, in my case the world.

I had thought that a combination of Intersect and Dissolve functions would get me what I wanted, but haven't had any success with this approach yet.

Can anyone suggest a better process?  I am open to any suggestions, whether it be some tools already available in ArcMap, QGIS...etc or through programmatic/scripting using ArcPy,GDAL...etc.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the output grid should be? When I think grid, I think of a raster, but maybe you are thinking of something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to do this would be to create a fishnet polygon layer using [Create Fishnet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) from the same extents as your bounding box layer, and divide it into an appropriate number of columns/rows.

Then perform a [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) with the target layer being the fishnet polygons and the join layer being your bounding box polygons. Do a **one to one** join; this creates a `JOIN_COUNT` field with the number of bounding box features that intersect each fishnet polygon.

Symbolize the output by `JOIN_COUNT` and you have a quick and dirty [heat map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map):

[image: Fishnet Heat Map]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.